# How can i stop VNC server from viewing my desktop

Tags: vnc

I work in an organisation. Today I found that system administrators have installed VNC server in my system. I came to know that now they could monitor my desktop and files. how can i stop them from viewing my desktop and files?

Comment: If the system belongs to the organization, there isn't much you can do because it is their property. Some organizations use it to administer support for large numbers of computers.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I stop them from viewing my desktop and files?

VNC is configured by default so that it first asks the user to allow access. This means that you will get a popup and the shared session is only started if you explicitly allow it.

But more importantly: IT simply is not allowed to look without asking. Obviously the rules vary per country, but in general they will first contact you (or you phone them to report some problem and ask for help). Only after that they will tell you that they are starting a connection to your system and even then you usually have to click on a popup to allow this.

> they could monitor .... and files.

As for monitoring files: Windows ships outof the box with admin shares enabled. The same rules apply. No monitoring by default unless there are very good reasons. (e.g. in a casino where this can be explicitly stated in your contract or in spcific IT rules and which you need to sign to confirm that you know this. Or when fraud is strongly suspected and management orders it.).

Comment: How does your statement that "IT simply is not allowed to look without asking" go along with "rules vary per country"? Yes they do vary, and I believe it's not guaranteed that anybody is required to ask. But besides VNC, there are even tools which make regular snapshots of desktops for the employer, and they're not illegal everywhere. -- Even if they're illegal where you work, you might use some Citrix thingy which is hosted elsewhere, moving the whole arrangement into a gray zone. (Writing this b/c I believe that I once worked for a company which illegaly moniteored computer desktops.)

Comment: If they illegally monitor then it becomes a legal issue. Not one to solve technically (and on a corporate desktop there is no way you can win that battle. You can sabotage, or try to. But you will never be sure.).

As per country rules: You do not mention which country you are in, but almost all EU countries have rules for this.

Comment: Isn't the intention to manipulate a computer owned by one's employer because one does not want to be monitored, given that it's not illegal to be monitored by one's employer in all countries, a legal issue in the first place?

Comment: No, because most of the time this tool is installed for legally allowed reasons. E.g. to help employees in a remote office.

Comment: You misunderstood my question.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i stop them from viewing my desktop and files?

There are plenty of ways to do it but you shouldn't try even one of them, that all could end up badly.

Here is a sample disclaimer by IT Department

[image]

If you read through carefully, you would understand:

- Why they do it ?
- You shouldn't care if you are doing what you are supposed to because they are being watched